# Importing (semi)-large CSV and Duplicate Data

Tags: mysql, import

I'm using MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import a CSV of about 150k rows nightly on a cronjob.

The table definition is simple (CSV contains all columns except for ID):

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id int(10) unsigned auto_increment
    category varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    subtype varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    manufacturer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    part varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY mfg_part (manufacturer,part)
);
```

**Problem:**
I'm not sure how to handle deleting records that are no longer in the CSV.

**My attempt:**
My idea was to add a batch number to the table and have LOAD DATA INFILE update each existing record with the latest batch number. A delete query would then remove all records whose batch number is not the latest. The load data query used for this is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/products.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `products`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`category`, `subtype`, `manufacturer`, `part`)
SET `batch` = $newBatchNumber
```

Doesn't work though because `SET batch` causes MySQL to see each row as a whole new record, rather than updating the old batch number to the new.

*Is there a way around this?*

As it stands, the only other alternative I can think of is to switch from LOAD DATA INFILE to batches of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queries.

Comment: If you want to have only records in your table that are also in the CSV file, then why not issue a `TRUNCATE Table` before importing the CSV?

Comment: I clarified my post a little. The CSV does not contain IDs, so a truncate could cause products to be imported with different ID's than before. Using ID's in URL currently, so it would break URLs. I suppose I could modify the URL structure so an ID is not necessary, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Hmm. Using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` wouldn't get rid of products that are not in the CSV file but do exist in the table, right? If I were you, I'd switch to using the real unique identifier in your URLs (manufacturer + part). Then you can simply do a `TRUNCATE` statement before your `LOAD DATA INFILE`. And if your DB server ever crashes, you'll still be able to regenerate the table without having to alter any URLs at all (which would be a problem if you keep relying on the arbitrary auto-increment column).

Comment: @Daan, If I were to use the INSERT query, I would run the DELETE query after it. I am considering using just the mfg+part combo for the URL though. It would make things easier in the long run.

Comment: Oh right, that's what the batch number would be for. Well, I'd still use the mfg+part combo, but maybe someone else has a great solution :)